# How to use extern across methods

Tags: objective-c

I hope someone can help.

I am writing a cordova plugin in objC to connect to an IOT platform called gizwits.

I'm trying to declare an extern variable in .h file, then assign a value in one method of .m then finally call that value in another method. But when I call the value in the final method i always get null.

.h file

```
extern NSString *const uid;
    extern NSString *const token;
```

.m file

```
    - (void)pushSSID:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

    NSString* ssid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* key = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *const uid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *const token= [command.arguments objectAtIndex:3];
    NSLog(@"%@", uid);//this displays my uid
    NSLog(@"%@", token); //this displays my token
```

callback

```
    -(NSString *)wifiSDK:(GizWifiSDK *)wifiSDK
    didSetDeviceOnboarding:(NSError *)result
            mac:(NSString *)mac
            did:(NSString *)did
     productKey:(NSString *)productKey {

        NSLog(@"%@", uid); // always null
        NSLog(@"%@", token); // always null
```

The callback always returns null for the uid & token. The callaback only runs when the value has alreayd been set in the pushSSID method.

If anyone has any suggestions I'll be so grateful. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```
NSString *const uid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *const token= [command.arguments objectAtIndex:3];
```

are not setting the global external variables. Those are separate, local variables.

Change those two lines  to:

```
uid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
token= [command.arguments objectAtIndex:3];
```

That will set values to the global variables.

Comment: thanks for you response. when I do this I get the error message 

`Cannot assign to variable 'uid' with const-qualified type 'NSString *const __strong'`

Comment: Remove the use of `const`. If you are changing the value then they are not constants.